# Group theory: Cayley's theorem

Tags: group-theory

> For $n$ large, we see that $G$ is a tiny subgroup of $S_n$, which has $n!$ elements, as compared
> to $n$ elements. In contrast, for $n$ small, the situation is quite different, as shown by the
> following examples. The group $\Bbb Z_2$ is in fact the same as $S_2$. (Check this; it’s trivial.). But
> the group $\Bbb Z_3$, with three elements, clearly cannot be the same as $S_3$, with $3!= 6$ elements,
> but it is the same as $A_3$. (Why?)

I was reading the Zee's book about group theory, as a beginner I am stuck in this citation above. $G$ is any finite group with $n$ elements, and we are talking about Cayley's theorem.

Comment: Looks like they're just comparing the groups $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $S_n$. Do you know what these two groups are? What is your question?

Comment: @GabrielaDaSilva There are a few things that the author says in this paragraph. Could you explain exactly what it was that you found confusing? What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: @ndhanson3

" The group Z2 is in fact the same as S2. (Check this; it’s trivial.) But the group Z3, with three elements, clearly cannot be the same as S3, with 3!= 6 elements, but it is the same as A3." Is the main problem, particularly, i am having trouble too with the definition of Z. 
As far as i know, Z2 for example is the group whose answers to x² = 1 are the elements.

So Z2 = (1,-1)


$Z3 = (1,e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3})$


But what’s that got to do with permutation?

Answer (score 2):

When the author says "the group $\Bbb Z_2$ is the same as $S_2$," he means that $\Bbb Z_2$ is **isomorphic** to $S_2$.

In particular, denote $S_2 = \{e,\tau\}$, where $e$ denotes the identity map and $\tau:\{1,2\} \to \{1,2\}$ denotes the transposition defined by $\tau(1) = 2, \tau(2) = 1$. The map $\phi:\Bbb Z_2 \to S_2$ defined by $\phi(e) = 1,$ $\phi(\tau) = -1$ is an isomorphism.

In the same vein: when the author says that $\Bbb Z_3$ is the same as $A_3$, he means that these groups are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Group theory is all about the underlying structure of the elements, not the way we write them. As you mentioned, we can view $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the set $\{1,-1\}$. In order to be a group and not just a set, we also must decide on the operation. Here it would be multiplication, and we get the following multiplication table:

\begin{array}{r|rr} & 1 & -1\\ \hline 1 & 1 & -1\\ -1 & -1 & 1 \end{array}

The group $S_2$ is usually written as the set $\{(12),\ ()\}$, where I just wrote $()$ to represent the identity, or do-nothing permutation, along with the operation of composition:

\begin{array}{r|rr} & () & (12)\\ \hline () & () & (12)\\ (12) & (12) & () \end{array}

As you can see, these sets and their operations look eerily similar, and in fact we say that they are the same group (technically, they are isomorphic groups). This happens if two groups have the same multiplication table, and the only difference is how the elements are written.

I'll let you explore the groups $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $S_3$. The book you're reading wants you to notice that there is actually a **subgroup** of $S_3$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ called $A_3$. Can you write out the multiplications for $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $A_3$ to show that?

Comment: If you wanted to write a literal multiplication table, you could write something like this:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rr}
\times & 1 & -1\\
\hline
1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
$$
(right click, go to "show math as... TeX commands" to see the LaTeX).

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't know how and was too lazy to google.